# Node.js string escape characters translation

Tags: javascript, node.js

[image]

The first case, I have use the `fs.readFileSync()` to read html content from the local file, and I call the `console.log()`,it output normally with format.

The second case,I use the regex to match the content from a text(not file), and it output with some escape characters.

For the second case, how can I translate the output just like the first case?Remove all the escape characters with format.

Comment: You just want to replace the escape characters only? Use replace()

Comment: no. I need to parse the special charaters like `\n`,`\"`,not just replace them to empty.

Comment: @HiufanI have the same question, did you get any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the escape characters using the Javascript replace method String.replace()

```
var newString = $3.replace(/\\n|\\/g,"");
console.log(newString);
```

Generally speaking, you can parse special charachters by putting an extra "\" before them. For example if you wanted to refer to "\n" in a string literally, you can use "\n". To replace any of the special characters in a string, do;

```
var newString = $3.replace(/\\n|\\/g,"string-you-want-to-replace-with");
console.log(newString);
```