# escape charaters are not interpreted while reading text from file in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

While reading string from file, escape characters are not being interpreted

**File Content: "Hello world\r\n\tTesting\r\n\tlastline\r\tthank you"**

```
var file = fs.readFileSync('./file.txt','utf-8');
console.log(file);

//Output
Hello world\r\n\tTesting\r\n\tlastline\r\tthank you
```

Same string working with Console.log()

```
console.log("Hello world\r\n        Testing\r\n    lastline\r\thank you");
//output        
Hello world
    Testing
    thank you
```

I found similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41739552/node-js-string-escape-charaters-translation?answertab=active#tab-top) but didn't solve my problem or accepted answered

Comment: opps, thanks @Louis-MarieMatthews fixed

Comment: I guess `\r\n` in your file is a string, not newline. And it work for me when I change the file content.

Comment: @Cr. file content string, i copied same string for console.log()

Comment: Why would they be interpreted?  It's not the job of a plain file reader function to guess that your file's content includes special meta characters.

Comment: @Alnitak I am new to JS, is there any way to interpret  escape charater like it does in console.log ?

Comment: It not the same ,your file content really string is `Hello world\\r\\n `

Comment: @Cr. its "Hello world\r\n\tTesting\r\n\tlastline\r\tthank you"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `readFileSync()` function has no idea that your file contains special meta-characters, it'll just return the raw data.

It's possible to convert the data yourself, though:

```
function unbackslash(s) {
    return s.replace(/\\([\\rnt'"])/g, function(match, p1) {
        if (p1 === 'n') return '\n';
        if (p1 === 'r') return '\r';
        if (p1 === 't') return '\t';
        if (p1 === '\\') return '\\';
        return p1;       // unrecognised escape
    });
}
```

It's unfortunately not possible to just return `'\' + p1` because only complete string literals are subject to escaping.

Comment: It's Working! Thanks a lot , is reverse possible too ?

Comment: Sure it's possible, but that's a whole other question

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function parseString(str) {
    return str.replace(/\\r/g, '\r').replace(/\\n/g, '\n').replace(/\\t/g, '\t')
}

var file = fs.readFileSync('./file.txt', 'utf-8')
file = parseString(file)
console.log(file)
```